# ASP.net Ajax: Use Code behind function instead web service

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Is it possible not to use web service for ASP.net ajax instead call code-behind function to fetch data?

any example or link is much appericate.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ASP.NET AJAX documentation](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) (at least for the AutoComplete TextBox control), if you do not provide the ServicePath property for the control to access, then the method that is to be called (specified in the ServiceMethod property) must be a page method.

I read this to say that you can simply create a method in your code behind file that matches the proper signature that the AutoComplete is expecting and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/sohailsayed/archive/2008/02/23/calling-methods-in-a-codebehind-function-pagemethods-from-client-side-using-ajax-net.aspx) seems to be what you are looking for.